Can the owner of a Google form see my email if I submit it?
Can the owner of a Google form see my email if I submit it?
I want to know if the creator/owner of a Google form that I submitted can see my email address or not. 

They may be able to depending on what the form settings were.  If they enabled the option to collect respondents' email addresses you should see a note in the form advising you that your email address will be collected.  This may be by entering an address or by being logged in to your Google account.
Also, if you received a form response after submitting then they definitely collected your email address as it isn't possible otherwise.  See View & manage form responses for more info.

I believe this is a clear, on-topic question (the link leads to the relevant [meta] post). As such, I voted to reopen it.

Please [edit] question for clarity.  Did you submit your email address? "Can the owner of a Google form see my email if I submit it?"    It would also be helpful if you indicated if you received an email confirmation after submitting the form.
